# Space vector modulation (SVM) for BLDC motor

Tags: inverter, brushless-dc-motor

I want to run a 4 pole bldc motor(12V) using SVM in open loop.

- microcontroller: Infineon
- IDE: Keil Microvision.

I have successfully generated the Space vector which starts rotating as shown in the pic.This space vector PWM is supplied to the Bridge drive(6 MOSFETs). But as soon as I start, a very high current flows. Why is so? Am I doing something wrong?
[Scope Video, 3 phase high side FETs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VgEE9XE5USeh34bWaotgLK4SvZ6VU33d/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I is not shown.  What is DCR?

Comment: Please check again, and let me know if you could see the scope video?

Comment: yes but not 3 phase ,,, more like 2 with PWM

Comment: Nobody's going to watch some video. Put the relevant info into the question - including Tony's question, the speed you're running the motor, and the motor parameters from its datasheet. What was your current prediction, and why, and how much does the actual current exceed that?

Comment: Brian Drummond, I think scope view is equally relevant. It shows 3 high side MOSFETs and low sides are complementary to the high side. I want to start the motor from stop to some 100 rpm in open loop sensorless mode.

Comment: examine RMS voltage from start, incorrect PWM duty cycle and do above

Comment: OK so now we know the speed is below 100rpm, but you should add it in the question - along with the other relevant information you haven't provided. What current do you expect and why? What back-EMF is the motor generating at these speeds?  Unless the motor's speed constant is really low (like 8rpm/V), so far it looks like the current is probably just what you would expect (from Ohms Law) driving this motor this way.

Comment: You should control Vrms/f to regulate current and torque in ramp up with PWM and SVM

Comment: "video format is not supported" - get rid of the video and put static information into your question.

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of reasons which will let the bldc draw a high current when you run it on your svm implementation.

1. If you are using hall sensors, then your rotor  position estimation could be giving erroneous values. those positions values are what you are giving to your svm. so if there is a problem with that, you will have a lot of problems with your motor
2. You could also be setting the Dwell times of the state vectors wrongly in your svm implementation. swap the Dwell times T1, T2
   each sector and see if it helps
3. in open loop, you need to add 90, ( try 180 if it doesn't work) degrees to your rotor  angle before you feed it to your svm